# Uniqueness of representation of elements of quotient by minimal polynomial in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $F$ be a subfield of $K$. It is easy to see that if $\alpha $ is algebraic over $F$, then its minimal polynomial $p(x)$ is (monic) unique and irreducible.

Taking the quotient, $F[x]/p(x)F[x]$ is a field (as $p(x)$ is irreducible), and any element $g\in F$ can be represented uniquely as $p(x)F(x)$+ a polynomial of $degree<n$, where $n=deg \ p(x).$
 I can immediately see that if instead of taking the minimal polynomial $p(x)$, we take any polynomial $f$ and quotient by its ideal $(f)$, we get a ring (not necessarly a field).

In this case, the representation does not need to be unique, right?

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: The representation of what is not unique ?
 $\ \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)  = \mathbb{Q}(di+e) \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/(ax^2+bx+c)$ whenever $\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2} = -d^2$

Comment: any  element $g\ in F[x] $ can be repesented ,by quotinent, $F[x]/p(x)F[x]$  as ${a_0+a_1*x+...+a_{n-1}*x^{n-1}}$. Is this representations  unique if $f$ is a random poly?

Comment: Yes of course it is unique : the elements of the quotient are of the form $\{  f(x) + (p(x)), deg(f) < deg(p) \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the representation is unique regardless of what (nonzero) polynomial $f$ is.  For any polynomials $f$ and $g$ with $f$ nonzero, there exist unique polynomials $q$ and $r$ with $\deg r<\deg f$ such that $$g=qf+r.$$ This is just the statement of polynomial division with remainder, which has nothing to do with whether the polynomials are irreducible.